# How to write a unit test for feature statistic the number of product sold

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I want to write a unit test for the below function. The function is the statistic of the number of products sold. I am looking forward to receiving your ideas for this problem.

```
public function index()
{
    $totalByToday = $this->productRepo->getProductSold('day');
    $totalByWeek = $this->productRepo->getProductSold('week');
    $totalByMonth = $this->productRepo->getProductSold('month');

    foreach ($totalByToday as $product) {
        $brands_today[$product->brand->name] = 
            $this->productRepo->getSumQuantity($product);
    }

    foreach ($totalByWeek as $product) {
        $brands_week[$product->brand->name] = 
            $this->productRepo->getSumQuantity($product);
    }

    foreach ($totalByMonth as $product) {
        $brands_month[$product->brand->name] = 
            $this->productRepo->getSumQuantity($product);
    }

    return view('admins.dashboard')->with([
        'label' => array_keys($brands_today),
        'quantity1' => array_values($brands_today),
        'quantity2' => array_values($brands_week),
        'quantity3' => array_values($brands_month)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: To test a route use an [http test](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests). If you want to just test the values you get then you should extract the code in its own utility class and unit test that

Comment: Do you give me an example if I want to just test the values get, such as I want to test array $brand_today so I do? @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

Use feature test instead of unit test so that you can test your index end point as a complete feature. To create feature test just use php artisan make:test YourTest

after that you can test your index like this.

```
public function testIndex() {
    // create your dummy data, use factory or seed them, it's up to you.
    factory(Product::class, 10)->create();

    // test your endpoint
    $response = $this->get('your end point url (eg. localhost:8000/your-route)')

    // your assertion that you need. it can be anything, see the documentation and choose what you need
    $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

That's it. It is a simple case of unit testing. For your case I think you want to see this documentation because you use blade template and view it directly

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#testing-views

If you are testing API endpoint with JSON response, I can help more, I always use API endpoint.

In order for this to work, you have to set up phpunit.xml correctly and have a fresh database. Use refresh database as well.